# InfoPath and SharePoint - Filtering lookups

Tags: list, infopath, lookup-column, filter

I have three SharePoint lists based on the below examples:-

**ListCountry**
CountryName : Single Line of Text

**ListCity**
CityName : Single Line of Text
RelatedCountry : Lookup [ListCountry:CoutnryName]

**ListBuilding**
BuildingName : Single Line of Text
RelatedCountry : Lookup [ListCountry:CountryName]
RelatedCity : Lookup [ListCity:CityName]

Now I want to setup an InfoPath form for the ListBuilding list so when I add a new entry I first select the country, then city, and then populate the building info.

The form can access both of these lists fine via drop downs however I’m struggling to setup a filter so that once I select the country only the City’s within that country are visible from RelatedCity lookup.

I know this is possible via InfoPath but can’t get it working, any pointers/ideas?

Many thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by 
 
1. creating a new data connection to retrieve a City & its respective Country. 
 
2. Change the Data Source of the "City" Drop down to use the new data connection and Apply Filter

Detailed steps are available in this link (Source):-
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/11/cascading-dropdown-using-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint-list.html